# RequiredFieldValidator not firing, but RangeValidator is fine

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, validation

My RangeValidator is working perfectly. My RequiredFieldValidator is not firing at all. Any ideas why?

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtTestNumber" runat="server" MaxLength="4" 
Text='<%# eval("LC") %>'></asp:TextBox>

<asp:RequiredFieldValidator  ID="rfvTestNumber" runat="server" 
Display="Dynamic" EnableClientScript="False" ErrorMessage="Required" 
ForeColor="Red" ControlToValidate="txtTestNumber" Enabled="true" 
ValidationGroup="WizStepValidationGroup">required
</asp:RequiredFieldValidator>

<asp:RangeValidator ValidationGroup="WizStepValidationGroup" 
Display="Dynamic" ID="rvTestNumber" runat="server" ErrorMessage="Invalid value" 
MinimumValue="0" MaximumValue="9999" ControlToValidate="txtTestNumber" 
Type="Integer"></asp:RangeValidator>
```

Thanks for your input!

Comment: So - you enter a number greater than 9999, and see no error ?

Comment: @sh1rts The RangeValidator is working fine. When I delete all info and move on the RequiredFieldValidator doesn't prevent me from going on. It should. Not sure why it doesn't work.

Comment: EnableClientScript="False" - don't you want 'true' ?

Comment: @sh1rts I don't think so.

Comment: "when i delete all info and move on the RequiredFieldValidator doesn't prevent me from going on" - if you're expecting something to prevent this client-side i.e. before you post the page, then you definitely will want EnableClientScript="true"

Answer (score 0):

Add the `ValidationGroup="WizStepValidationGroup"` property to the text box and the button.

**UPDATE:**

You have set `EnableClientScript="False"` of `RequiredFieldValidator` hence it is not getting validated at the client side. Hence remove the `EnableClientScript` property or set it to `True` and I am 100% sure then it will work.

Comment: Still didn't work for some reason. But, great idea. :)